# How to read first numbers from file in C++

Tags: c++, input

I have txt file like this.

```
51.5u-07
-6.5 -10      
55u-10
-7 -10    
55u-10
-7 -10    
55u-10
-7 -10    
54u-10
-7 -10    
54.5u-10
-7 -10    
55u-10
-7 -10    
54.5u-10
-7 -10    
55.5u-10
-7.5 -10
```

I want to read this file, get all odd line's value into vector of int, vec1.
get all even line's value into vector of int, vec2.

such as vec1 is [51.5, 55,55,55,... 
vec2 is [-6.5, -7, -7, -7...]
can anybody help me this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to read one number? Can you read 2? Can you put a number into a vector? Which part do you find difficult?

Comment: Firstly, those are `double` or `float` values, not `int`.  Secondly, please show what code you have so far.  Exactly what part of this are you having trouble with?  Is it reading files, parsing values or adding to vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read both numbers at once using `fscanf`:

```
double first;
int second;
scanf("%lf%*[ u]%d", &first, &second);
```

The "magic" is in the format string: it reads a `double` using `%lf`, then skips a space or a `u` using `%*[ u]`, and finally reads an `int` using `%d`. Do this in a loop, pushing the `first` and the `second` variables onto the two vectors as needed.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/CnmXAm).